# Creating and evaluating digital signed signatures for authentication etc

Tags: encryption, cryptography, pgp

This question is triggered by an email from Microsoft this morning about a security bulletin.  It started with

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256
```

and ended with a PGP signature.

I've seen this before but hadn't given it much thought previously.  But upon reflection I have no idea if this email is actually from Microsoft (I'm sure it is, but bear with me).

How does one go about verifying a message like this?  To start with, I was able to find Microsoft's Security Center public key here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/pgp

I presume this is the public key that I could use to authenticate the message I received (and validate it).  This being so, HOW do I do it?  There's got to be freely available software out there to enable this task, but which should I use?  Or perhaps is there a dynamic link library out there somewhere that I could use to do such authentication and validation programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to use e-mail client, capable to handle PGP-signed|encrypted messages.
2. Properly configured, with imported **(trusted)** public key, MUA will tell you, owner of public key signed mail or not